# Compact = Closed + Bounded + (?)

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ we know (Heine-Borel Theorem) that a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

In $C(X)$ for a compact metric space $X$, we know (corollary of Ascoli-Arzela Theorem) that a set is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded, and equicontinuous.

I am looking for as many examples as I can of other spaces where the extra condition for compactness is known.

Also, I am looking for as many examples as I can of (important) spaces where the extra condition is *not* currently known.

I am planning on doing some research (under a professor) and I thought this topic was particularly interesting, so I would very much appreciate some examples to start off with, just so I can get a feel for the problem.

Comment: Would you consider the [result that any metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofThatAMetricSpaceIsCompactIfAndOnlyIfItIsCompleteAndTotallyBounded.html) as being of this form?

Comment: Here you have the L^p version of Ascoli-Arzelà: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet-Kolmogorov_theorem

Comment: And let's not forget [Montel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem) from complex analysis, which classifies the compact subsets of $\text{Hol}(U)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Banach spaces, there is a big table in Dunford & Schwartz characterizing compactness of subsets in many different spaces.

Zev is right that "complete + totally bounded" is the general formulation.  For subset in Banach space, complete holds if and only if closed.  So the question is to characterize total boundedness.

Comment: Thanks, GEdgar! What is the book by Dunford & Schwarz?

Comment: Tim: Just Google "Dunford and Schwarz" (or, better, "Dunford and Schwartz") and you'll figure this out yourself.

Comment: @KCD: Thanks! Found it.